# What does "cannot load such file -- ruby-debug" indicate when running require?

Tags: ruby

Hi:  I've been asked to debug some ruby code, a language I know next to nothing about, so please bear with me.  FWIW, the port is from v 2.1.1 to 2.3.1

This is the ruby script...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$VERBOSE = nil

begin
  $:.unshift File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)), '..', 'lib'))
  require 'idl'
rescue LoadError => e
  puts "Failed to load idl library. #{e}"
  exit(-1)
end

GC.disable # Disable GC since IDL is so transient. The GC takes an inordinate amount of time
IDL::App.instance.run
```

This is the error message...

```
Failed to load idl library. cannot load such file -- ruby-debug
```

The ruby script is in a dir which ***does*** have a sibling dir that has the idl library...

```
-> ll idl ../lib
-rwxrwxr-x 1 joe thegrp  348 Feb 26 17:29 idl

../lib:
total 12
drwxrwsr-x 3 joe thegrp 4096 Feb 21 11:44 idl
-r--r--r-- 1 joe thegrp 4327 Feb 21 11:44 idl.rb
```

All of this appears to have worked in 2.1.1

I don't think this is a matter where it can't find the library.  I stuck some debug statements in the ruby script which just print out the value of... File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(File.realpath(**FILE**)), '..', 'lib')) and it's right on. And remember, this exact same code and dir structure worked in 2.1.1 .

Could it be that the "cannot load such file" is really trying to say "I can't load this library because it was created in 2.1.1 and this is 2.3.1" ??

What's up with the "-- ruby-debug" ?

I found some notes (internal) that "ruby-debug" could be an issue.  The subject was...

```
errors related to deprecated debuggers like pry-debugger, debugger, ruby-debug
```

The solution was...

```
Use pry-byebug debugger
```

I'm not sure why a debugger is being invoked here or if it's the reason for the error.  And I'm not sure how to "Use pry-byebug debugger".  Is there a way I can  stick this in the ruby script, something like "use pry-byebug" ?

Any help deciphering what's happening and any proposed solutions would be appreciated !

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found my own answer.

A .rb file inside the library had a...

```
use 'ruby-debug'
```

I changed that to..

```
use 'pry-bugbye'
```

and it worked.

IOW, the error message was all about the use of "ruby-debug".  And the solution was indeed to replace that with "pry-bugbye"

Hope this posting helps someone else in the future !

Comment: Congrats on figuring this out!